# How can I fix this union problem in my sculpt?

Tags: mesh, sculpting

So I blocked the major body parts out, I unioned the legs and torso together but I forgot to apply the scale data and I think a mirror modifier as well. [image]Is there a way I can fix this or do I have to start over?

Comment: do you mean you have 2 separate meshes? In that case it can't be fixed in Sculpt mode, you need to boolean... But actually if you're glad with the left part you could symmetrize it going into the Mesh menu > Symmetrize, and choose the axis in the Operator box